# Is cyclic replacement inconsistent with ZFC-Foundation?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axioms

**Replacement:** if $\phi(x,z)$ is a formula in which all and only symbols $``x,z,x_1,..,x_n"$ occur free, and non of them occur as bound, and in which the symbol $``B"$ never occur; then: $$\forall x_1,..,x_n \\\forall A \exists B \forall y \ [y \in B \leftrightarrow \exists x \in A \forall z (\phi(x,z) \leftrightarrow z=y)]$$; is an axiom.

The above scheme is a just a reformulation of the axiom schema of replacement.

**Cyclic replacement** is the above schema but with allowing the symbol $``B"$ to occur free in $\phi(x,z)$.

> 1. Is it inconsistent to replace axiom schema of replacement in ZFC-Foundation by axiom schema of cyclic replacement?
> 2. Would that be inconsistent with Aczel's anti-foundation axiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something here, Cyclic Replacement is inconsistent with just about any set theory. If $p$ and $q$ are two distinct sets, let $\phi(x,z,B)$ be $(z=p\land B\neq\{p\})\lor(z=q\land B=\{p\})$. Let $A$ be your favorite nonempty set.  (Since you insist that $\phi$ contain $x$ free, add a clause "$\land(x=x)$".)Then cyclic replacement says there's a set $B$ such that (1) if $B=\{p\}$ then $B=\{q\}$ and (2) if $B\neq \{p\}$ then $B=\{p\}$. That's contradictory.

Comment: Possibly $$\forall x_1,..,\forall x_n \\\forall A \exists B \forall y \ [ \exists x \in A \forall z (\phi(x,z) \leftrightarrow z=y) \to y \in B ]$$ might salvage it?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Let $\phi$ say that $z$ is the first ordinal not in $B$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I know now how to salvage this approach, the formula $\phi(x,z)$ must be a disjunctive formula $\psi(x,z) \lor \varphi(x,z)$ where only $B$ only occurs in $\varphi(x,z)$  which must be a positive formula (defined as in positive set theory), clearly cyclicity is anathematic to negation. a possible other way is to use acyclic (stratified) formulas.